# Android DrawerLayout + FAB issue

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, floating-action-button

I'm having an issue with my android drawer layout, which includes a floating action button as well as a custom implementation of a GLSurfaceView.

The problem is that when I have the FAB in my layout, everything works as expected. When I remove the FAB from my layout, however, I get some weird results.

Here is my layout.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.me.myapp.NavDrawerActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.me.myapp.NavDrawerActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.me.myapp.MySurfaceView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/surface"
               />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />



    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_nav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

It looks as expected:
[image: looks ok]

But when I remove the FAB tag, I get this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here??

Answer (score 0):

change RelativeLayout to this:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.me.myapp.MySurfaceView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/surface"
               />

</RelativeLayout>
```